# Cyrillic phonetic alphabet?

Tags: phonetic-symbols

Is there any attempt to make phonetic alphabet (like IPA) based on Cyrillic script?

Or does the Russian phonology covers enough?

Comment: I thought this was going to be about an equivalent to the NATO phonetic alphabet :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few authors that use the Russian Linguistic Alphabet ([Русский лингвистический алфавит](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82)) or a variation of it. For example [Balgina 2002](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books2/xbook107/01/index.html?part-020.htm#i1481) (see sections 56, 57, 58).

Answer (score 7):

Nowadays, most major publications use IPA, and among those that don't, it's usually for historical reasons. Creating new phonetic alphabets isn't a particularly active area of research when there are already multiple standards that work well enough. (Some people do come up with *extensions* to the IPA, and some of those extensions eventually end up standardized, like the tone-bar letters—but they're still using the existing standard as a base, not starting from scratch.)

However, some of the non-IPA standards do include some Cyrillic characters, such as the Uralic `ᴫ` for a postvelar lateral. The usual trend across different systems seems to be to use Latin characters first and foremost, then Greek, then Cyrillic, as need be. So if you find yourself needing a letter for something the IPA (or Americanist or Uralic or whatever) doesn't support, Cyrillic isn't a bad source to draw from.